# Gurobi- How to use indicator constraints in version 7.0?

Tags: optimization, gurobi

The newest version of Gurobi allows for the use of [indicator constraints](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/constraints.html#subsubsection:GeneralConstraints) but I can't figure out from the user manual how to implement these with the Matlab API.

Comment: Does the Matlab API even offer nice ```addConstr``` functions in general? It always looked like there is only the possibility to construct the matrix-form by yourself (which would probably render these new functions impossible to use). The Python docs on the other hand clearly shows how to use them (which might indicate even mor that Matlab is lacking this). **Thanks for this question as i did not notice that there is a new major release!**

Comment: If the option is not available for Matlab. I wonder how easy it is to export a model written in Matlab into python or something else and add those constraints.

Comment: That's a good question. I would't have to high hopes as this sounds complex regarding the internals. But this can be checked quite fast. The main question here is just: do you really need this? They don't offer anything which could not be done before, but just makes it easier (at the cost of some intransparent decisions internally i would assume; e.g. bigM values).

Comment: You may be right, I really don't know how they work. I was hopping that they have some nicer way of implementing them that bigM.

Comment: I don't think there is anything else than bigM and SOS-based (the latter having customized paths during solving). But i'm just guessing. I'm quite optimistic that Gurobi-dev Greg Glockner will help us out here as he is quite active on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, indicator constraints are not supported by the Gurobi MATLAB and R interfaces.  These interfaces use a matrix representation.  For example, for a linear program in canonical form:

max c<sup>t</sup> x
Ax = b
x ≥ 0

The interface takes the matrix A and vectors b and c, and returns the optimal solution.  Unfortunately, this means that high-level representations like piecewise linear functions or indicator constraints are beyond the scope of the MATLAB and R interfaces.  They are available for Python, if that helps.